# Nginx failed question programs not downloading

Tags: nginx

Now when I try to install anything this happen there is a problem with nginx and I don't know how to fix it.

```
-----@----:~$ sudo apt-get install nginx
[sudo] password for _____: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done


The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer 
required:
account-plugin-tools account-plugin-ubuntuone colobot-common
colobot-common-sounds colobot-common-textures libboost-locale1.58.0
libgsm1:i386 libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 libmircommon5 libmircommon6
libmirplatform11 libmirplatform13 libmirserver38 libodbc1:i386 libpay2
libphysfs1 libpoppler-qt5-1 libqt5bluetooth5 libqt5bluetooth5-bin
libqt5keychain0 libqt5location5 libqt5location5-plugins
libqt5positioning5-plugins libqt5purchasing5 libqt5quickparticles5
libqt5versitorganizer5 libqt5websockets5 libsdl-ttf2.0-0 libu1db-qt5-3
libubuntu-app-launch2 libubuntu-location-service3    libubuntuoneauth-2.0-0
libzmqpp3 linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-    4.4.0-70
linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-70-generic
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-72-generic mir-client-platform-mesa5
-graphics-drivers-desktop mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms12
mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms8 mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x12
mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x8 mir-platform-input-evdev5
mir-platform-input-evdev6 pay-service pay-ui pinball-data policykit-unity8
python3-gnupg qml-module-pamauthentication0.1 qml-module-qmltermwidget1.0
qml-module-qt-websockets qml-module-qtbluetooth qml-module-qtlocation
qml-module-qtorganizer qml-module-qtpositioning qml-module-qtpurchasing
qml-module-qtquick-localstorage qml-module-qtquick-particles2
qml-module-qtsensors qml-module-qtwebsockets
qml-module-ubuntu-mediascanner0.1 qml-module-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser
qml-module-ubuntuone qtdeclarative5-poppler1.0 qtdeclarative5-u1db1.0
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-mediascanner0.1 qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-push-plugin
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-syncmonitor0.1
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-telephony-phonenumber0.1
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-thumbnailer0.1
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-extras-browser-plugin
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-web-plugin qtdeclarative5-usermetrics0.1
qtubuntu-appmenutheme qtubuntu-desktop qtubuntu-print signon-plugin-password
snap-confine system-image-common system-image-dbus
ubuntu-application-api3-desktop ubuntu-html5-ui-toolkit ubuntu-printing-app
ubuntu-push-client ubuntu-sdk-libs ubuntu-terminal-app ubuntuone-client-data
ubuntuone-credentials-common unity-scope-click
unity-scope-click-departmentsdb unity8-desktop-session
unity8-desktop-session-mir wine-devel wine-devel-amd64 wine-devel-i386:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
nginx
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 3,490 B of archives.
After this operation, 37.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 nginx a ll 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 [3,490 B]
Fetched 3,490 B in 0s (6,533 B/s)
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
(Reading database ... 558722 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb ...    
Unpacking nginx (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Setting up nginx-core (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error    code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
'invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-08-31 18:09:43 EDT; 11ms ago
Process: 32582 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 32578 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 31 18:09:40 Reimann nginx[32582]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f...e)
Aug 31 18:09:40 Reimann nginx[32582]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f...e)
Aug 31 18:09:41 Reimann nginx[32582]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f...e)
Aug 31 18:09:41 Reimann nginx[32582]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f...e)
Aug 31 18:09:42 Reimann nginx[32582]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 f...e)
Aug 31 18:09:42 Reimann nginx[32582]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Aug 31 18:09:43 Reimann systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, ...=1
Aug 31 18:09:43 Reimann systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web ...r.
Aug 31 18:09:43 Reimann systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 31 18:09:43 Reimann systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result        'exit...'.'
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) |        nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2); however:
Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
Package nginx-full is not installed.
Package nginx-light is not installed.
Package nginx-extras is not installed.
nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2.1~); however:
Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
Package nginx-full is not installed.
Package nginx-light is not installed.
Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
        Errors were encountered while processing:
nginx-core
nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
-------@------:~$
```

So the question is what did I destroy inadvertently I ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and get similar errors?

Answer (score 1):

Dependency errors created by `apt-get` can usually be solved by running `sudo apt-get -f install`. If that doesn't solve the issue, edit your question.

Comment: I tryed that before posting the question and I got the same error message